# php mandrill api integration rejects hotmail

Tags: php, mandrill

I integrated the Mandrill API integration with codeigniter. For yahoo, gmail the emails received fine. But for hot mail the emails did not receive. What is the problem here. Shall we pass pass anything additional in the headers? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Actually, i have the same problem. Even if i put an Hotmail email in the mandrill whitelist and my MX is valid, Mandrill ignores some emails or use a huge delay to send them. I'm pretty sure that comes from hotmail server..